# Backspace key not working Ubuntu gnome 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, backspace

I recently realized the backspace key has stopped working. I was messing around in the keyboard shortcuts the other day and wondered if I changed it inadvertently, but looking back I couldn't see where I might have made the mistake.

Any suggestions on how to get backspace functionality back?

To be clear, backspace does not work in Ubuntu in any application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `setxkbmap -option backspace:backspace` in your terminal.

Restart your computer.

If above doesn't work, check if your backspace is working at all.

If your backspace is not working at all, you just reassign the backspace to another key (caps lock preferably) by using the same code as above like `setxkbmap -option caps:backspace`